# Content Delivery presentation site failing with unable to find valid tridion home

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, 2013-sp1, ambient-data-framework

Presentation server is failing with the following error.

Tridion Version: 2013 SP1

Tridion Home is properly set and it contains all the required lib, config & license file.

```
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130560186647618695 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\TridionContentDelivery\PresentationWebSite_Staging\ 
    Machine name: pres-web 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 2032 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: TargetInvocationException 
    Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

The type initializer for 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule' threw an exception.
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule..ctor()

Exception occurred during configuration callback
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.ToJavaString(String str)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add_string(String str)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add(Object obj, Type type)
   at Org.Slf4j.LoggerFactory.GetLogger(String name)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Utilities.LoggerFactory.GetLogger(String loggerName)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule..cctor()

Unable to locate a valid Tridion Home directory, see Tridion event log
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.ConfigurationHook.ConfigMethod(IJvmLoader loader, Int32 when)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level)



Request information: 
        Request URL: http://localhost/ 
        Request path: / 
        User host address: ::1 
        User:  
        Is authenticated: False 
        Authentication Type:  
        Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

    Thread information: 
        Thread ID: 8 
        Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
        Is impersonating: False 
        Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
       at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
       at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)


    Custom event details:
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For .NET Web Application the Tridion Home is dynamically setup by `JuggerNET`. It will check for the presence of an `HttpContext`, if it is true, then it will check for the presence of a `Bin` folder containing `Config` and `Lib` folders, if it cannot find them then it will try to find a [TRIDION_HOME] in the Environments Variables. Make sure you have a Bin folder with the above setup.