# Getting Error message "Unable to locate a valid Tridion Home Directory" while accessing Contact Profilesync.aspx page

Tags: 2013, audience-manager

I am getting error message "Unable to locate a valid Tridion Home Directory" while accessing Contact Profilesync.aspx page. Below is the Event log of the said error. Could you please help me to fix the error.

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-2-130771136739520509 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: \XXXXXXXXXX\Repository\synchronization\ 
    Machine name: XXXXXXX018

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6240 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: APPS\Ptridionweb

Exception information:

> Exception type: JuggerNETFrameworkException 
>       Exception message: Exception occurred during configuration callback
>      at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level)
>      at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader()
>      at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.ToJavaStringPinning(String str, Int32 length, IntPtr& result)
>      at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.ToJavaString(String str)
>      at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add_string(String str)
>      at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add(Object obj, Type type)
>      at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add(Object obj)
>      at Com.Tridion.Marketingsolution.Utilities.Settings.Validate(String currentURL)
>      at Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Utilities.Settings.Validate(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse)
>      at Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Profilesync.Handler.ProcessRequest(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse)
>      at Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Synchronization.Profilesync.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> Unable to locate a valid Tridion Home directory
>      at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.ConfigurationHook.ConfigMethod(IJvmLoader loader, Int32 when)
>      at Codemesh.JuggerNET.ConfigurationHook.Invoke(IJvmLoader loader, Int32 when)
>      at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level)

Comment: It looks like a configuration error, where you're missing some element from anconfig file. Can you share your cd_storage_conf.xml, or if you're on an older version, then your cd_broker_conf.xml?

Comment: Please check if this helps: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/content-delivery-presentation-site-failing-with-unable-to-find-valid-tridion-hom/7963#7963

Comment: Thanks Nickoli. Your clue helped me to fix the issue. Thanks once again.

Comment: Could you accept an answer to this question? If my answer is not good enough, you can always provide your own. It helps future users with the same problem if they know what solved the issue for you.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message indicates, it was unable to locate a valid "Tridion Home" directory.

The "Tridion Home" directory is a term for the directory containing the Tridion JAR and configuration files.

Tridion Content Delivery looks for such a folder in the following places:

1. The *bin* directory from the current web context (e.g. Server.MapPath(“~/bin”)). This is only used if there is an *HttpContext* available (e.g. running within a web site).
2. The current directory, as returned by *Environment.CurrentDirectory*.
3. The *TRIDION_HOME* registry value (HKLM\Software\Tridion\Content Delivery\General)
4. The *TRIDION_HOME* environment variable.
5. The default Tridion installation folder (C:\Program Files\Tridion)

It will validate each of those in turn and move on to the next one if deemed invalid. The location is considered valid if:

- The directory exists.
- It has a *lib* subfolder containing the CD JAR files such as *cd_core.jar* and *cd_model.jar*.
  -It has a *config* subfolder containing the CD configuration files such as *cd_broker_conf.xml* or *cd_storage_conf.xml*.

You can tell which location it has settled on by looking for “Content Delivery.NET” events in the Tridion event log. You will see a message such as “Using HttpContext current bin directory as Tridion Home”.