# Unable to locate a valid Tridion Home directory - After upgrade from SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, upgrade, sdl-tridion

I am getting the below mentioned error while accessing a web application after upgrade the SDL Tridion from 2011 SP1 to 2013 SP1.

> Unable to locate a valid Tridion Home directory

Complete Tridion Stack trace is given below:-

> [TridionConfigurationException: Unable to locate a valid Tridion Home directory, see Tridion event log]
>      Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.ConfigurationHook.ConfigMethod(IJvmLoader loader, Int32 when) +422
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) +570
>   [JuggerNETFrameworkException: Exception occurred during configuration callback]
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) +869
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader() +64
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.ToJavaStringPinning(String str, Int32 length, IntPtr& result) +87
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.ToJavaString(String str) +81
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add_string(String str) +248
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add(Object obj, Type type) +325
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add(Object obj) +62
>      Com.Tridion.Util.TCMURI..ctor(String uri) +122
>      Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Utilities.TcmUri..ctor(String tcmUri) +39
>      Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI.ComponentLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +138
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
>      ASP.templates_newdefault_master.__Renderform1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Websites\sadc_intertnet\Templates\newdefault.master:148
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
>      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +395
>      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +49
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
>      ASP.templates_newdefault_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Websites\sadc_intertnet\Templates\newdefault.master:100
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
>      System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5363

I have checked the environment variable for Tridion_Home is already set. Also I have checked the registry keys for Tridion_Home, correct path is there.

Just for more update, CMS is working fine, the problem is comming at setup the site at CD environment on same server(CMS and CD are on same server).

Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: In which point the error is happening, It's not clear the steps you followed to upgrade from one version to another. Have you checked the Event Log as it sugest in the log? If the error is in the application, which type is (.net or java) and how is the architecture (same machine, different machines), etc. Try to be more clear and gives us more clues.

Comment: The error comes from one of the Content Delivery services. Can you please check solutions provided here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11901/getting-error-message-unable-to-locate-a-valid-tridion-home-directory-while-ac and here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/content-delivery-presentation-site-failing-with-unable-to-find-valid-tridion-hom/7963#7963

Comment: @RaúlEscudero I am getting the error while loading the home page.
I have upgraded the DBs and install the SDL Tridion 2013 Sp1 with Legacy feature.
In Tridion Event log, i am not getting anything related to Tridion_Home directory.
And in Application event log, same error message is showing as i have mention as stack trace.
Application type is .net and architecture like CM and CD are on same server and Database is on different server.

Comment: @StanislavMaryenko Thanks for the reference but i have followed the both but could not resolve my issue.

Comment: do you have correct java installed - check with java -version. Also, the Tridion_Home - does this exists as a variable for a specific user or as a System User?

Comment: can you execute on CMD echo %TRIDION_HOME% with successful result? Did you restarted the IIS after upgrade webapp's configs and jars?has the user of ApplicationPool rigths on %TRIDION_HOME%?

Comment: @Pankaj I have checked the Java version and it is seems correct as CMS is working fine and all the things are working at CMS end. Getting error while loading web application. Also the Tridion_Home directory exists for all the users. Thanks

Comment: @Jose - I have executed the given command and there is no error or ambiguity. Yes i restarted the IIS several times. Application pool user also has the rights on Tridion_Home directory.

Comment: could you upload an image with security rigths on %TRIDION_HOME% folder? if not, could you check if there are rights for  MTSUser and NETWORK SERVICE?

Comment: does your website bin have config and lib folders containing tridion configs and jars?

Comment: @Jose I have uploaded the access detail image which show that Network Service and MTSUser has rights on the %Tridion_Home% directory.

Comment: @PankajGaur My webapplication doesn't have lib folder inside the bin.There is only config folder which contains cd_storage.xml file only.My webapplication and deployer are pointing to a central directory for jar files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kindly check .jar files and DLL versions and make sure they are as per Tridion 2013 SP1. Its seems there is some issue with the version mismatch.

Comment: I have checked the versions and copied the jar files from a running application to the common directory on the server. But It doesn't work for me and its not pointing to the Tridion_Home directory. Is there any alternative by which we can bypass this error. Thanks

Comment: @Sumit.. The most important thing is that you must check and put the JAR file and/or configs at the right place - In case you are having a bin\lib and bin\config in the executing website location, then this will supersede over the bin\lib and bin\config folder available in your Content Delivery setup.Ensure you have these missing JAR files and/or configs in these directories of your executing application if this is the case along with your Content Delivery setup

kindly try to put the lib and config folder inside bin folder of your application

Comment: Hi Hemkant, after putting the lib folder in application's bin folder we got error for linking. After searching for the error we were able to resolve the issue now. Thanks